# Update entire column with new column values based on id

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

Using MySQL, my current table looks like

Table A:

```
 id_u | date       | other | calculation
----------------------------------
    1 | 2019-09-09 | ""    | 1
    2 | 2019-09-09 | ""    | 1
    4 | 2019-09-09 | ""    | 2
    5 | 2019-09-09 | ""    | 4
```

And I have a query (SELECT) that returns

Query:

```
 id_u | calculation
-------------------
    2 | 12
    4 | 16
```

Wanted result after update :

```
 id_u | date       | other | calculation
----------------------------------
    1 | 2019-09-09 | ""    | 1
    2 | 2019-09-09 | ""    | 12
    4 | 2019-09-09 | ""    | 16
    5 | 2019-09-09 | ""    | 4
```

---

How is it possible to update the `calculation` column for each ids ?

Comment: "Yes, it is possible"

Comment: Hint : Search `UPDATE using JOIN`

Comment: What results do you want?  What does "without code" mean?

Comment: I added the result I wanted. I meant "without code" meaning only in SQL, without having to use php/java/scala

Comment: Word around is you need an UPDATE query to make an update.

Comment: `UPDATE tableA JOIN (<..your SELECT query>) dt ON dt.id_u = tableA.id_u SET tableA.calculation = dt.calculation` Basically you utilize your `select` query as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) and join it back to main table for updating the main table.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya That's actually what I want, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MySQL`, you can use the `JOIN` clauses in the `UPDATE` statement to perform the cross-table update :

```
update tableA a inner join (
  select id_u, calculation   
    from <some table[s][joins]>
) b on a.id_u = b.id_u 
   set a.calculation = b.calculation;
```

where, in this case, the `derived table`, which is an expression that generates a table after the scope of a query `INNER JOIN` clause, is used.

Comment: This answer is lacking an educational explanation.

Comment: @mickmackusa I agree re good answers but this answer is worthless anyway because the question is an obvious basic easily-found duplicate & should be downvoted, closed & deleted.

Comment: @phil show me your best nomination.  If it's a good one, I'll support it. (I'm neck-deep in answering something else at the moment.)

Comment: @mickmackusa The question has no clear specification, it's just example fragments from which we are to guess, so I really should have said, it would be a faq when clear. Also see the comments on the question. This is all so obvious I can't bring myself to waste any more time on this. Thanks for trying to improve answers.